# Properties of a function without partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)$ be a function such that $f(sx, sy) = s f(x,y)$ for some positive real $s$. Let $f_x(y)$ and $g_y(x) = f(x,y)$ be single variable analogues of $f$, and suppose $f_x(y)$ and $g_y(x)$ are continuously differentiable. I'd like to show that $f(x,y) =  y f '_y(x) + x g'_y(x)$ for all positive $x,y$.

Using partial derivatives this isn't too hard. I'm wondering whether there is a solution that does not use any multivariable calculus, as it doesn't seem necessary for this problem.